# Swift 3 error when accessing NSUserDefaults, why?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift3

I'm having a fatal error when executing the following code:

```
 func dateChange()
{
    let dateNow = Date()
    var oldDate = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as! Date
```

Here's where I get this error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode= 0x1002a91fc) when accessing the oldDate through UserDefaults.

```
    let timeDifference = dateNow.timeDifference(from: oldDate)

    if timeDifference > 1
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Schade", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        days = 0
        defaults.set(days, forKey: "days")
    }
    else if timeDifference == 1 && challengeCompleted == true
    {
        days += 1
        defaults.set(days, forKey: "days")
    }

    oldDate = dateNow
    defaults.set(oldDate, forKey: "oldDate")
}
```

I just don't get why I get this error message. I got the same when accessing this code:

tvc.data = tvc.defaults.array(forKey: "data") as! [String]

I'm loading an array from another view controller in this case.

What really makes me curious is, that I **only get this message, when running the app on my iPhone, not in the simulator.** I just don't get it. Can anyone help me?

Thank you for having a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the first time launching the app and you have not yet set anything in user defaults for "oldDate". This will only be nil the first time a user uses your app.

In the file AppDelegate.swift you could add the code below to didFinishingLaunchingWithOptions

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "oldDate") == nil {
      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Date(), forKey: "oldDate")
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: @Whazzup Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if a value is present in the key or not before unwarping the optional value:

```
if let sample = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as? Date
{
    var oldDate = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as! Date
}
```

Comment: You don't need oldDate, as sample will now contain the value of oldDate from defaults...

Comment: didn't work :/ well actually it worked, but I still get an error at the place where I try to use it... Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Because I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good joke about using force-unwrap "*every time you use force unwrap somewhere in the world a kitten dies*".

That means: Don't use force unwrap.

In your example,

`var oldDate = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as! Date`, you are trying to get something that is not there by forcing it, and obviously if it's not there it will fail miserably.

There are several ways of fixing this:

1. Use the optional value

   ```
   var oldDate = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as? Date
   ```
2. Unwrap the value inside the defaults

   ```
   guard let date = defaults.object(forKey: "oldDate") as? Date else { return }
   ```

The common way is to `return` in case the unwrapping didn't go well, but it is your choice what you want to do with it.